# python: problem with dictionary get method default value

Tags: python

I'm having a new problem here .. 
CODE 1:

```
try:
   urlParams += "%s=%s&"%(val['name'], data.get(val['name'], serverInfo_D.get(val['name'])))
except KeyError:
   print "expected parameter not provided - "+val["name"]+" is missing"
   exit(0)
```

CODE 2:

```
try:
   urlParams += "%s=%s&"%(val['name'], data.get(val['name'], serverInfo_D[val['name']]))
except KeyError:
   print "expected parameter not provided - "+val["name"]+" is missing"
   exit(0)
```

see the diffrence in serverInfo_D[val['name']] & serverInfo_D.get(val['name']) 
code 2 fails but code 1 works

the data

```
serverInfo_D:{'user': 'usr', 'pass': 'pass'} 
data: {'par1': 9995, 'extraparam1': 22}
val: {'par1','user','pass','extraparam1'}
```

exception are raised for for data dict .. and all code in for loop which iterates over val

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) (dict.get):

> Return the value for key if key is in
>   the dictionary, else default. If
>   default is not given, it defaults to
>   None, so that this method never raises
>   a KeyError.

That is why your first code works and second doesn't.

Comment: @goutham: This is exactly why you need to post your error message. I had no idea what the problem was.

Comment: @goutham: You should also accept answers. The questions you asked earlier have been answered, but you have not accepted many of them.